# How to install Lubuntu 18.10

Tags: partitioning, software-installation, lubuntu, acer, 18.10

I have an Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 14 AO1-431 with a 32GB hard disk. I need help on how to install Lubuntu 18.10 on my laptop. When I try to install it every time it goes in the part where it says where to install Lubuntu on which hard drive. It says to create a partition for installing Lubuntu on, and it is confusing.

Comment: Single boot only dont need windows

Comment: It doesn't show me that when i go to the installer when i hit the partition part it only shows manual partition and that part i dont know how to do my system has like 2 gb ram and a 32 GB drive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/)

Comment: It tells me to configure EFI systems partition

Comment: Please don't reuse my duplicate link. This question is about how to configure EFI systems partition as mentioned in the preceding comment.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know about partitions, stop the installations and search online about it.

http://www.control-escape.com/linux/lx-partition.html

Basically your operating system needs three main partition:

root(/): This is where your operations system files go.
It uses ext4 file system.
I suggest give this area at least 18GB.

swap: This is used as virtual memory. It allows your computer to run complex apps even if you don't have enough physical memory.
This partition doesn't have any file system, when you allocate space for it, you should select swap area in file system.
You can give this area between 50% and 100% the size of your memory.

home(/home): This is where your personal files go.
This partition also uses ext4 file system.
Give all the remaining space here.

**This will format your hard drive and delete all the files.**

Again.
If you don't know what you're doing and you have personal data on your Hard Drive, **STOP** the installation and search online until you're confident about what you're doing.

Comment: But when i do that it tells me to configure EFI sytem partition

Comment: It has something to do with /boot, check this article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI